# Solve $(y')^2 = 1+\dfrac{1}{y^2}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Ignore the initial condition for now, I am interested in knowing how to solve the following ODE:
$$ (y')^2 = 1 + \frac{1}{y^2}. $$
I tried multiplying $y^2$ on each side and obtain:
$$ (yy')^2 = \left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}y^2\right)^2 = y^2 + 1, $$
but this leads me to nowhere. A good hint is what I am looking for to get me going.

*It looks like one requires some "clever" observation to solve this, or I am just being stupid and forget how to solve ODEs.*

Comment: You missed a factor of $2$ in your second equation. But then replace $y^2=u$ and take square root on both sides.

Comment: $y = i$ is a solution.

Comment: Don't forget that $(y y')^2 = y^2 + 1$ could mean either $y y' = \sqrt{y^2 + 1}$ or $y y' = - \sqrt{y^2 + 1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows that
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \pm \sqrt{1 + y^{-2}}\\
\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1 + y^{-2}}} = \pm \int dx
$$
and your equation is separable

Comment: It is separable......... I had it actually but thought it wasn't separable at first glance, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$(y')^2 = \frac{y^2 + 1}{y^2}$$

$$y' = \pm \frac{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}}{y}$$

Case 1 -

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}}{y}$$

$$\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}} dy = dx$$

Integrating both sides,

$$\int \frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}} dy = \int dx$$

$$\frac 12 \int \frac{2y}{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}} dy = x + c$$

$$\sqrt{y^2+1} = x + c$$

Case 2 -

$$y' = - \frac{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}}{y}$$

Hope you can solve it.